# Chart.js canvas element has negative height and width in Chrome 60

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I'm using Chart.js to display some information when a user clicks on data in another chart.  When chart 1 is clicked, 3 additional charts are created, this are the ones that are having the issue.  They work fine in both firefox and Edge. Only Chrome is displaying this behavior.  Once I resize the screen, just a tiny bit, the chart resizes itself, and looks fine.

I looked at this, which shows an issue with chrome and the z-index, but that doesn't appear to have gone anywhere.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=155483

Any ideas on what could be going on?

[image: screenshot of issue]
[image: screenshot of console]

Fleet chart click event handler

```
//EVENT HANDLERS
$("#fleetSummaryChart").on('click', function (evt) {
    var activeBars = fleetSumChart.getElementsAtEvent(evt);
    var label = activeBars[0]._view.label;
    var tempArr = label.split('(');
    var station = tempArr[0].trim();
    var unit = tempArr[1].replace(')', '').trim();

    stationunit_selected = findIndexByKeyValue(stationUnitDetails, 'StationName', 'UnitName', station, unit) || 0;

    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        //store the selected unit in session storage for loading data in other pages
        sessionStorage.setItem('stationUnitDetails',JSON.stringify(stationUnitDetails[stationunit_selected]));
    }

    setUnitDetails();
    refreshDoughnuts(); <---- THIS IS WHERE THE CHARTS ARE BEING CREATED

    $("#unitDetailsContainer").show();
    $("#rTripContainer").show();
    $("#tTripContainer").show();
    $("#derateContainer").show();

    //THE LINES BELOW WHERE ADDED AND I BELIEVE THIS CORRECTED THE ISSUE


   derateFunctionCht.chart.width = 0;
   reactorTripFunctionCht.chart.width = 0;
   turbineTripFunctionCht.chart.width = 0;

   derateFunctionCht.resize();
   reactorTripFunctionCht.resize();
   turbineTripFunctionCht.resize();

});

function refreshDoughnuts() {
    var tTripsData = getTurbineTripChartData();
    var rTripsData = getReactorTripChartData();
    var drateData = getDerateChartData();

    if((typeof turbineTripFunctionCht === "object") && (turbineTripFunctionCht !== null)){
        turbineTripFunctionCht.destroy();
    }   

    if((typeof reactorTripFunctionCht === "object") && (reactorTripFunctionCht !== null)){
        reactorTripFunctionCht.destroy();
    }
    if((typeof derateFunctionCht === "object") && (derateFunctionCht !== null)){
       derateFunctionCht.destroy();
    }

    turbineTripFunctionCht = new Chart(turbineTripByFunction, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: tTripsData,
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        min: 0,
                        max: 1,
                        fixedStepSize:0.1
                    }
               }]
            },
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    fontColor: '#000',
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    fontSize: 15
                }
            }
        }
    });

    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#000';
    Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 15;
    //Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle = 'bold';

    reactorTripFunctionCht = new Chart(reactorTripByFunction, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: rTripsData,
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    fontColor: '#000',
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    fontSize: 15
                }
            }
        }
    });

    derateFunctionCht = new Chart(deratesByFunction, {
        type: 'horizontalBar',
        data: drateData,
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                labels: {
                    fontColor: '#000',
                    fontStyle: 'bold',
                    fontSize:15
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue while using Chart.js a few weeks ago. For me it was the responsive option in the Chart options causing it to resize incorrectly. A solution could be to manually resize the canvas immediately after it is created using jQuery, but it is hard to know for sure unless you provide the code that is responsible for initializing the charts.

Comment: Here is the issue that I opened/closed with Chart.js in case you may find the discussion useful: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4397

Comment: I'll post some of the code that is creating the charts.  One thing that I've noticed is that when another item is selected from chart 1, the 3 charts that are displaying the issue, display fine the second and around.

Comment: A couple suggestions: Try setting `responsive: true` as an option and make sure that you are assigning a size to the element surrounding the `<canvas>` element or the canvas might be getting "squished" by whatever element is around it.

Comment: The surrounding div is `<div class='col-md-12'>`, which already has the position:relative style set, which what chart.js recommends. I added the `responsive:true` to the option of the first chart, but no change

Comment: So I believe I fixed it.  I tried `benogle` response on Jan 10, 2017 from this github post https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/512   I have updated the code to show where I added the those lines.